# How to Naming ShapeContainer in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, canvas, shapes

i try to make an application that draw network map 
i use a panel in form and into this panel created dynamically ShapeContainer as canvas.

in this canvas i create some shape and line dynamically (for create these shapes i use two method )

for lineshape :

```
private void CreateLine(int StartX,int StartY,int EndX,int EndY,Color lineColor,String ControlName)
    {

        LineShape newline = new LineShape();
        canvas.Parent = panMap;
        newline.Parent = canvas;
        newline.StartPoint = new Point(StartX+ZoomScale , StartY+ZoomScale );
        newline.EndPoint = new Point(EndX + ZoomScale, EndY + ZoomScale);
        newline.BorderColor = lineColor;
        newline.BorderWidth = 2;
        newline.BorderStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
        newline.Name = "Link_" + ControlName;
        newline.Tag = "Link_" + ControlName;
        newline.BringToFront();
        canvas.Shapes.Add(newline);


    }
```

and for create rectangle i make this method:

```
private void CreateBox(int X, int Y, int ObjectType)
    {
        ShapeContainer canvas = new ShapeContainer();
        RectangleShape box = new RectangleShape();
        box.Parent = canvas;
        box.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 90);
        box.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
        box.Name = "Box" + ObjectType.ToString();
        box.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        box.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        box.BackgroundImage = img.Images[ObjectType];
        box.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        box.BorderWidth = 0;


    }
```

i call these method like this :

```
        CreateBox(600, 160, 4);
        CreateBox(600, 200, 3);

        CreateLine(75, 83, 227, 176, Color.Green, "1");
        CreateLine(227, 176, 367, 95, Color.Green, "2");
```

---- now , i have some problem :
1. how to set name for this shape (for use in other method)?
    for example in textbox control i use this :

```
TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)Controls["txtCityName"];
```

what can i do for shape ?

1. how to create method for this shape ?
   for example :

   newline.Click += newliclick(object sender,EventArgs event,Color linecolor) !?

i want send more than 1 object to method

excuse me for long question and sorry if i can't describe my question (my English language not well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not like that.Your method signature should match with the event handler.You can create a class by inheriting from `EventArgs` but it seems unnecessary in this case.

Anyway,just define a method for event handler and another method to do your job that takes `Color` parameter.Inside of your click event call your other method and pass `Color` parameter.For example:

```
newline.Click += newlineClick;

private void newlineClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newlineClickImpl(sender,e, Color.Blue);
}

private void  newlineClickImpl(object sender, EventArgs e,Color color)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: it work , tnx . but i need send name or index of newline to method. please show me what code need if i want show newline name , tag or index. (in form load call CreateLine() or CreateBox() several time. tnx again.